# Could the magnet used in smartphone covers damage the device?

Tags: touchscreen, case, mobile-phone, smartphone, magnet

I am reading reviews of a smartphone cover with magnetic lock and some people reported that the magnet causes their phone screen to go dark. why is this happening and could this actually damage the device?

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't damage the device.

The screen goes dark because the phone is designed to turn off the screen when a magnetic cover is closed. If someone designs a cover with a magnet in the wrong place, it's a crappy cover.

Answer (score 1):

Tentative no (I'm not an electrical engineer).

On old CRTs magnets cause distortion and damage as they distort the coating on the back of the glass that the stream of electrons hit. Modern LCD panels aren't subject to magnetic damage like this as the electrons barely move at all before dissipating as the screen cycles.